# Javascript gem seen but not loaded

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

The problem has been the same with both gems [`jquery_mask_rails`](https://github.com/maurcarvalho/jquery_mask_rails) and [`jquery-inputmask-rails`](https://github.com/marcosnogueira/jquery-inputmask-rails). (examples use the latter)

If I add the relevant line in `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery.inputmask.bundle
```

but not the following in the Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-inputmask-rails'
```

I get the following error when triggering a view, so the JS files are seen somewhere in the asset pipeline:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'jquery.inputmask.bundle' with type 'application/javascript'
```

With both lines in `Gemfile` and `application.js`, the `ActionView` stops showing up, but in the `development` environment, the corresponding `<script>` element isn't visible in the HTML and the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.iban-field').inputmask('AA99 **** **** **** **** **** **** **** **');
});
```

triggers a JS error:

```
$(...).inputmask is not a function
```

Comment: Did you try with the instructions on the [jquery-inpumaskt-rails Installation section](https://github.com/knapo/jquery-inputmask-rails#user-content-installation)?

Comment: Oh, you're using a different one, that's six years old. Same question, did you try using the instructions? What you're attempting to `require` seems incorrect.  You also didn't verify that you actually bundled it.

Comment: I also don't know what you mean by it's "seen but not loaded", it's specifically telling you it's *not* seen, evidenced by "[...] couldn't find [...]". "Can't find" == "not seen". It *tries* to find it because you *told* it to try to find it, but you're using a name different than what the instructions say to use.

Comment: I only see the ActionView error when the line isn't in the Gemfile. So yes, it IS seen, as evidenced by that error disappearing.

Comment: @DaveNewton I tried with 'knapo/jquery-inputmask-rails' and I get the same result.

Comment: Removing it from the gem file doesn't remove it from the disk. You're still requiring the wrong thing, based on their documentation. Did you try it following their instructions? Did you leave production build artifacts that would affect the dev build (this is a common mistake)?

Comment: When I switched to knapo's version, I changed the require to match its instructions. I actually copy/pasted the lines from the README.

Comment: And what happened then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193098/discussion-between-nowhere-man-and-dave-newton).